# How to have a select_tag drop down to associate items with lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I have Item and List models and they are both associated. List `has_many` items and an item `belongs_to` a list

Schema:

```
  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "list_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.boolean  "completed",  default: false
  end

  create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
    t.string   "permission", default: "private"
  end
```

I want to create a view (most likely `items/new.html.erb`) so when a user creates a new item, there will be a drop-down option for the user to select which list it belongs to. There will be a pre-defined list in the beginning (i.e.: `List` `name`: `"Home", "Work", "Personal"`). Any item that user makes will be associated to either one of those three.

Right now I have an Item `new.html.erb` view that takes in simple item name and `list_id`.

```
  <%= form_for @item do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :name, size: "24x12" %><br>
    <%= f.label :list_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :list_id %><br>
    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Entering `list_id` manually is very inconvenient; after researching, it seems like `select_tag` is the best form helper to do the job.

[image]

[image]

How can I build a `select_tag` that displays 3 drop-down List that a user can choose from to associate an `Item` to `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use `select` since you use form to achieve this. since you mentioned `List name` are pre-defined you can do it like this:

```
 <%= f.select :list_id,  options_for_select([['Home', 1], ['Work', 2], ['Personal', 3]]), {:include_blank => true} %>
```

**Note:** `['Home', 1]` home has an id of `1` here `{:include_blank => true}` to include blank.